# When my website loads, the CSS glitches for a second

Tags: css, web

When i open my website https://tobia-web.wz.cz/me?lang=en , for a second it looks like half the CSS disappeared. Why is this happening? Is it just loading in, or any actual problem with CSS/JS?
[image: This is how my website looks the very second it loads.]

Comment: What does your CSS look like? Where and how are your linking the CSS in your HTML file?

Comment: @computercarguy sorry i forgot. https://tobia-web.wz.cz/me/style.css and i use a link tag.

Comment: You need to add your code to the question so we can see it without having to go off-site. You might want to review the [How to ask a good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to make sure you get good answers and avoid down votes.

Comment: @computercarguy i wasn't sure because it is super long and a lot of it would be probably unnecessary.

Comment: That falls under the "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem." topic in the article I linked. Include just enough code to reproduce the issue. You probably don't need to include your whole CSS or your page to reproduce the issue, unless your CSS is so massively long that it takes a significant fraction of a second to download. And if that's the case, you probably need to find a way to decrease it's size.

Comment: Looks like some animation, but since everything is moving, it's hard to tell which part of it is unexpected for you.

Answer (score 0):

add "defer" keywords to `<script>` tag. example:

```
<script src="./js/main.js" defer></script>
```